# Codeigniter order by time - query generation

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I actually need a mysql query like

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(pri_hours, ':', pri_minutes, ' ', IF(pri_ampm = 1, 'am', 'pm')) as hr FROM (`sms_primary`)  ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(hr, '%h:%i %p')
```

and as I use codeigniter i wrote query as below

```
       $this->db->select("*,CONCAT(pri_hours,':', pri_minutes,' ',IF(pri_ampm = 1,'am','pm')) as hr",FALSE);
       $this->db->from('sms_primary');
       $this->db->order_by("STR_TO_DATE(hr,'%h:%i %p')");
```

But i am not getting the expected query i get it as below

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(pri_hours, ':', pri_minutes, ' ', IF(pri_ampm = 1, 'am', 'pm')) as hr FROM (`sms_primary`) ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(hr, `'%h:%i` %p')
```

I hope you spot out the difference in the generated query. Its a injection off some unwanted operator `. I just want to remove it.How to do that?

Change

```
STR_TO_DATE(hr, `'%h:%i` %p')
```

to

```
 STR_TO_DATE(hr, '%h:%i %p')
```

Comment: STR_TO_DATE(hr, '`%h:%i` %p')

Comment: sorry. I didnt get you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

codeigniter is adding backticks. use this before your query

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You require to use this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;

In your query,it should be like :

`$this->db->_protect_identifiers = FALSE;  // Make it false here
$this->db->order_by("STR_TO_DATE(hr,'%h:%i %p')");

$this->db->_protect_identifiers = TRUE;   // Make it true again when order_by code completed`

Comment: Thanks.. and you are right. But I got the answer already by kamran

Comment: Sorry i am unable to give you the green tick